# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen' in urllib3

Tags: python, urllib3

I have checked other posts, but the solutions did not seem to work. I keep getting the AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen' error. Any ideas why this wouldn't work be greatly appreciated.

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import urllib3

page = requests.get('http://www.sfbos.org/index.aspx?page=18701')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

#This will create a list of buyers:
proposal_doc_date = tree.xpath('//ul[@title="Date List"]/li/a/text()')
pdf_url = tree.xpath('//ul[@title="Date List"]/li/a/@href')

print 'Proposal Date ', proposal_doc_date
print 'Proposal PDF ', pdf_url

def download_pdf(url_list):
    for i in url_list:
        response = urllib3.urlopen(i)
        file = open(proposal_doc_date[i], 'wb')
        file.write(response.read())
        file.close()
        print("Completed")

download_pdf(pdf_url)
```

Comment: You already have requests, so why are you using urllib3?

Comment: I am very new at this, so maybe that is a stupid thing to do. How would you recommend using requests to download the PDFs?

Comment: Anyways, urllib3 doesn't have urlopen on the module. You can refer to the documentation for proper usage. Urllib2 does, though.  https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: You should pick one HTTP library and stick with it. Your fifth line of code that you download some html from a url is no different than the code needed to get a PDF from a url

Comment: you are getting an error saying that urllib3 doesn't have anything called `urlopen` because **urllib3 doesn't have anything called `urlopen`**. are you looking for [`urllib.urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen)?

Comment: It appears as though `urlopen` does work, but it is part of PoolManager(). Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're importing both [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/) and [urllib3](https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/) which serve the same purpose (requests is built on top of urllib3). Here's how to do this using requests:

```
import requests

# ...

http = requests.Session()

def download_pdf(url_list):
    for i in url_list:
        response = http.get(i)
        file = open(proposal_doc_date[i], 'wb')
        file.write(response.content)
        file.close()
        print("Completed")
```

And similar scenario in urllib3:

```
import urllib3

# ...

http = urllib3.PoolManager()

def download_pdf(url_list):
    for i in url_list:
        response = http.request('GET', i)
        file = open(proposal_doc_date[i], 'wb')
        file.write(response.read())
        file.close()
        print("Completed")
```

There are all kinds of other things you can do with streaming requests and writing the response to a file as it streams. Check out the documentation for the respective project for more.

Answer (score -1):

urlopen seems to be method of urllib3.connectionpool.HTTPConnectionPool class

https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pools.html#urllib3.connectionpool.HTTPConnectionPool.urlopen

Comment: URL is not opening.